# Is there a way to do a table lock using Sequelize for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create multiple records on a database table that requires me to count the number of existing rows in the table before creating them.

There will be concurrent calls of this function and I need to ensure that each request is atomic. I am using transactions with a transaction level of SERIALIZABLE. However when both transactions start at the exact same time before the transaction level is set, then the transactions actually run in parallel

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: I'm using Postgres

Comment: Something like `sequelize.query('LOCK TABLE '+tableName, { transaction })`?